# Document conversion and viewing, what are the cutting edge solutions?

Tags: html, pdf, converters, docx, doc

Goal: building a web application where a user can:

1. Upload a document (doc, docx, pdf, additional office formats a +)
2. View that document in a browser, preferably in html
3. Download the document (in doc, pdf, additional open formats a +)

Current solution:

- Ruby on Rails Application on Rackspace
- Users can upload doc and pdf files (AWS)
- Files can be downloaded in the format in which they were uploaded
- Thumbnail generation ([doc, pdf] -> pdf -> png) is done through AbiWord. Certain doc files do not convert well.
- Documents can be viewed in embedded Google docs viewer (https://docs.google.com/viewer). Certain doc files cannot be displayed. Little flexibility.

Potential improvements:

- Document viewing in pdf through [pdf.js](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/)
- Viewing in html (+ annotation) through [Crocodoc](https://crocodoc.com/)

I'd be glad to hear other users' experiences, and will add good recommendations to this list.